# Missing some rabbitMQ messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, amqp

I have strange issue, while broadcasting messages to clients.
This is my code, that is responsible for publishing messages:

```
AMQP.start(:host => property(:amqp_host), :vhost => property(:amqp_vhost), :user => property(:amqp_user), :pass => property(:amqp_pass)) do
      exchange = MQ::Exchange.new(MQ.new, :topic, "games" )
      exchange.publish( @message, :key => @key )
      AMQP.stop { EM.stop }
end
```

I'm using old version of AMQP gem(rails 2.3.8). The problem is -
When there is only one client, this client gets all messages, if there are more than 1 client, all messages gets last connected client. I've tried to publish to different keys, and split clients through pool of available keys, but still same. Is there something i've missed?

Comment: Could you post some client code? Could it be that the consumers(clients) are declaring queue with exclusive flag?

Comment: @cantSleepNow, - client code using https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc implementation, but as far as i know clients does not use exclusive flag

Comment: ok, but I can't say if the exclusive flag is true or false. This is a just a objc lib that the consumers are using.

Comment: @cantSleepNow i can confirm that exclusive flag is off!

Comment: Ok, thx! Unfortunately I don't have any more ideas...

Comment: Do you know if how many Queues are bounded to this Topic exchange and with what Keys? Most probably its issue with the routing keys